# Regular expression lookahead and/or lookbehind wrong in that

Tags: perl, regex-lookarounds

**$line = 'bob never ever said every reverie was good';**

Looking: Match and capture ONLY the word 'ever'. Do so using lookahead and/or lookbehind assertions.

```
if ( $line =~ /(?<=\s)ever(?=\s)/) {
 print "matched ";
}
```

substituting: Remove the word 'ever' and the space after it from the line using any mechanism you'd like.

```
$line =~ s/ever\s+//;
print $line ;
```

Extra-Credit: Get the character offset into the string of the word 'ever' using any mechanism you'd like.

```
my $result = index($line,'ever');
print $result;
```

I have wrote the exam. but i am not passs through. What is wrong in these answers ?

Comment: should it match or fail when "ever" is at the beginning of $line? At the end of $line? Before the newline at the end of $line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. "Match and **capture**". /(?<=\s)(ever)(?=\s)/
2. $line =~ s/ever\s+// will not remove **word** "ever", it will remove "ever" from "never". "\b" should be used here.
3. Same as 2, would find "ever" in "never", so you should search for " ever " instead and add 1 (because of adding space). You can add another 1 if you consider that 1st character in string has offset 1.

Comment: i didnt get you for answer 3#

Comment: @joe I think Alexandr means that a) you should include the leading space when searching for 'ever', otherwise the 'ever' bit of 'never' will be located; b) you should add 1 to the return value of index, as index starts counting at 0, but a human would probably assign the value 1 to the string's first character.